# iOS How to auto release a method in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I try to invoke this method for one time ever the apps is install and launch for the first time.

My idea is to fill the core data table with my data.

How to auto release this method in viewDidLoad?

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{

    if ((firstRun!=YES)) {

        NSLog(@"The data was already Added");

    }

    else {

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
        NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [newManagedObject setValue:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"new"] forKey:@"name"];
        firstRun = NO;

        // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by auto releasing the method??

Comment: shouldnt ARC do it for you automatically?

Comment: He is trying to verify if it's the first running... still, i don't know why he wrote "auto release"

Comment: if I have a button I use this code `UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;` but if i won't to use a button i need to run this method automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to verify if it's the first run.

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *userDefaultsDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"firstRun", nil];
    [prefs registerDefaults:userDefaultsDefaults];
    BOOL firstRun = [prefs boolForKey:@"firstRun"];

    if (firstRun==YES) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
        NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [newManagedObject setValue:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"new"] forKey:@"name"];

        // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
        [prefs setBool:NO forKey:@"firstRun"];
        [prefs synchronize];
    } else {
         NSLog(@"The data was already Added");
    }
}
```

You can call this method in your `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidLoad` with `[self insertNewObject:nil];`

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I wanted to do ;)